# Retrieving Android studio project from application on phone

Tags: android, android-studio

My team and I have been working on a project for the past few month. We had programmed an android application but the project was lost after our laptop was stolen. 
Is there any way to get back the project (java files, xml, gradle) from the application installed on the phone? (the latest version of the application is running on the phone).

Comment: Unfortunately, You can't reverse engineer the APK to get that much information, otherwise everyone would be doing it. I would suggest using a Git repository next time.

Comment: visit this application this may help you: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.njlabs.showjava&hl=en
sorry for your loss.

Comment: Thank you @JaydeepPatel! the java decompiler worked.

Comment: Happy to help :-)